# CDV variable, cordova variable and FB variable are missing

Tags: facebook, cordova

I'm a newbie and trying to make fb login via my app. am using corodva with ionic framework. i followed some tutorials and made reference to all three .js files. But when i run the app, it puts up an error stating variables are missing. help me out! This is how i made the references,

```
<script src="phongap.js"></script>
<script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>

<script src="facebook-js-sdk.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am also facing this issue but didn't get any solution if your issue is resolved please give some suggestion to me Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix typo.

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```